# SOAP-ERROR: Encondig

Tags: php, soap

I've created a object and added it to a array: `$array_propriedades[]`

```
            $prop = new PropriedadesSoap();
            $prop->PROPRIEDADE = 'FORMA_ARMACAO';
            $prop->VALOR = $this->input->post('forma_armacao');
            $array_propriedades[] = $prop;
```

And another object, that will be sent to the service like this:
Notice I'm sending the `$array_propriedades` on `$x->PROPRIEDADES`

```
$x = new PropriedadesSoap();
    $x->ID_CLIENTE = $this->session->userdata('usuario')->ID;
    $x->NOME_PRODUTO = $this->input->post('produto');
    $x->OS = $this->input->post('os');
    $x->PROPRIEDADES = $array_propriedades;
    $x->FK_TIPO_PRODUTO = (int)$this->session->userdata('tipo_produto');
    $x->SEU_NOME = strtoupper($this->input->post('nome'));

$pedido = new SoapClient(VendaSO, array("exceptions"=>1));
$res = $pedido->SalvarPedido($x);
```

I have a class PropriedadesSoap() with nothing inside so I can put everything I want, it was working without the FORMA_ARMACAO property but now I get this error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'FORMA_ARMACAO' property
```

I have no idea of what to do. I've read a article that the user used $pedido->__getTypes() and it worked, not for me, unfortunately.

Any help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry friends, the problem was happening on the service, the programmer forgot to add some parameters and that is why PHP wasn't able to encode the property.

Hope it helps.